# MATLAB: wait for return from a .NET process

Tags: .net, matlab

Is there a way to wait until a java or .NET process exits apart from using `pause()`? Using an example from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8932157/3850072

```
while true
    if proc.HasExited
        fprintf('\nProcess exited with status %d\n', proc.ExitCode);
        break
    end
    fprintf('.');
    pause(.1);
end
```

I was trying to use `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = '\wait';` or even `proc.WaitForExit();` but these attempts didn't work. I can achieve what I want by using the `system` command instead, but in that case the output window of the console doesn't get displayed.

Comment: Whats about `system('start /wait ping 127.0.0.1')`? Uses system command and opens a new window

Comment: I should clarify: I can either make system wait by calling `status = system('C:\SIMPACKv8.9\spck.bat')` or let the output be shown by `status = system('C:\SIMPACKv8.9\spck.bat &')`, but in the second case Matlab continues, it doesn't wait for the process to be finished. `ping 127.0.0.1` didn't seem to do anything...