# Method for asynchronous process manipulation in Linux based matlab

Tags: linux, matlab

I'm essentially trying to find a Linux compatible version of the .NET solution to the post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931000/how-to-execute-a-dos-command-from-matlab-and-return-control-immediately-to-matla/8932157#comment62398924_8932157). The goal would be to start a process and have control return to matlab, but also have the ability to continuously check the status of the process to determine when it has finished and if it returns any error codes.

I realize the system command does this but if you add the & at the end to return control back to matlab it returns the exit code and does not update when the process finishes.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try the java version in the same answer?

Comment: @Daniel I have not, are you thinking that it may work properly on both linux / windows? Ah, it does in fact say it may work on non-Windows systems. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: You have to replace the commands in the first two lines, otherwise it works.

Comment: @Daniel So I've been able to run some simulations using the Java version from the previous post. But, as soon as I execute the command I get an exit code of 0, then the simulation proceeds to run for 1 hour and after it completes I still get an exit code of 0. I'd like a way to tell if the simulation is running versus when it has finished. Is this possible? The .NET functionality allows this with a HasExited property of the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo class. Here is a snippet of the important bits [PastebinLink](http://pastebin.com/7dje0qjh)